# Why does Intro js element selection not work in mat card

Tags: angular, typescript, intro.js

I have created a tour, added step and ids to elements. But a element that is **nested in**, **is an angular component** or **is from a library that is for angular** will not be highlighted.

This is my tour:

```
this.introJS.setOptions({
      tooltipClass: 'customTooltip',
      highlightClass: 'customHighlight',
      exitOnOverlayClick: false,
      disableInteraction: false,
      steps: [
        {
          intro: 'Welcome to the web let me show you around!',
        },
        {
          element: '#step2',
          intro: 'Go to Home',
          position: 'right'
        },
        {
          element: document.getElementById('step3'),
          intro: 'Fill out the form',
          position: 'right'
        },
        {
          element: document.querySelector('#step4'),
          intro: 'Click Create an account',
          position: 'right'
        }
      ]
    }).start();
```

This is the html:

```
<div>
  <mat-card>
    <mat-card-content>
      <form id="step3" [formGroup]="testForm">
        <h3>test</h3>
          <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
            <mat-label>label</mat-label>
            <mat-select formControlName="role">
              <mat-option>1</mat-option>
            </mat-select>
          </mat-form-field>
      </form>
    </mat-card-content>
  </mat-card>
</div>
```

This is what the tip looks like:
[image]

It's in the centre and doesn't highlight anything

Edit:
If CyC0der's answer is correct then I have problem with using the ngnIntroService. I can't seem to get it included correctly. I created another question just for that issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68907669/importing-angular-intro-js-gives-error-angular-intro-js-is-not-a-module).

Comment: Where are those elements you want to highlight? I guess you don't need to use `element: document.getElementById('step3'),` but rather css selector.

Comment: When you look at my html there is element with id: step3, that's the element I want to highlight.

Comment: Have you tried to use #step3?

Comment: I have tried #step3, querySelector('#step3'), querySelectorAll('#step3')[0], getElementById('step3')

Comment: You don't need to use querySelector because there is no such element on a page yet. It needs time to be rendered

Comment: I have a function that loops and when it renders it will start the tour.

Comment: Is it only a problem with `mat-card`?

Comment: I just tested your code and it worked for me. Form is highlighted

Comment: @yurzui Did you also test highlighting mat-card? Also it's very weird that highlighting from has worked for you, I'll look into it a bit more.

Comment: Yes, I tested it with mat-card

Comment: I started using shepherd and it works a lot better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to reproduce the issue by integrating [intro.js](https://introjs.com/) into an angular application. And I am able to make it work properly. check here: [https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ylv4c2](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ylv4c2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Following are the highlights of the above stackblitz example.

I used the id property for all the elements.
`<mat-card class="example-card" id="step1">`

I called `introJs()` function inside `ngAfterViewInit()` life-cycle hook so that introJs can find all the elements it need to run the intro properly.

```js
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
   this.initIntroJs();
}

initIntroJs(): void {
    introJs()
      .setOptions({
        tooltipClass: 'customTooltip',
        highlightClass: 'customHighlight',
        exitOnOverlayClick: false,
        disableInteraction: false,
        steps: [
          {
            intro: 'Welcome to the web let me show you around!'
          },
          {
            element: document.getElementById('step1'),
            intro: 'Material Card Component',
            position: 'right'
          },
          {
            element: document.getElementById('step2'),
            intro: 'Material Grid Component',
            position: 'right'
          },
          {
            element: document.getElementById('step3'),
            intro: 'Material Button Component',
            position: 'right'
          }
        ]
      })
      .start();
  }
```

So I think it is a straightforward solution. You must be missing anything in the integration process. you can have a look at my solution and let me know in the comments if it works for you or not.

Comment: Your stackblitz works perfectly but when I tried to do it in my project I cant seem to get it working in my project. I did everything same as you but when I add `id` to material components or their children it stops working.

Comment: What is weird is that you didn't import introJs in your component, this gives me an error IntroJs is not defined.

Comment: Ok I found out that the problem isn't with material components but with nested elements. Also `exitOnOverlayClick: false` and `disableInteraction: false`. I still don't get why is it happening and trying to find out. Also I have to declare introJs like this:  `private introJs = introJs()` otherwise it is not defined.