# Importing angular-intro.js gives error angular-intro.js is not a module

Tags: angular, typescript, intro.js

I have tried:

```
import ngIntroJS from 'angular-intro.js/build/angular-intro';
import ngIntroJS from 'angular-intro.js/src/ng-intro.component';
```

But I get errors with both.
What is the correct way to import angular-intro.js and ngIntroService?

This is my angular.json

```
            "styles": [
              "./src/styles/root.scss",
              "./node_modules/intro.js/introjs.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "./node_modules/intro.js/intro.js",
              "./node_modules/angular-intro.js/build/angular-intro.min.js"
            ]
```

Basic IntroJs has worked for me when imported like this:

```
import * as introJs from 'intro.js/intro';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"styles": [
              "./src/styles/root.scss",
              "node_modules/intro.js/introjs.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/intro.js/intro.js",
              "node_modules/angular-intro.js/build/angular-intro.min.js"
            ]
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't post code-only answers but add a little textual explanation about how and why your approach works. You may also have a look at our ["How to write a good answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) entry.